# Is there a way to capture events when non-content objects added/deleted/modified?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm specifically talking about SharePoint objects such as Views, Lists, WebParts, etc, not items such as the actual content in lists.  I realize this would probably have to be something the resides locally on the server probably using the client context, as opposed to a web service API.

One example: Someone modifies an existing List View setting.  I want my .NET app/library to get notified of such activity so that I can then interrogate that view to see what changed from the previous instance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE! You have a very interesting question there, which I myself would like to have an answer on. If I would guess, I would place my bets on PowerShell, but I haven't seen anything yet. Nice to see you here!

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at the Change Log - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417456(v=office.14).aspx - Quite a rich API for querying, though you'd have to have a Timer Job that runs and looks for the relevant changes, and then runs the code you need.

Comment: I wonder if taking this a step further, such as using the Sql Query Notifications option (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) to "listen" to the underlying SharePoint SQL content database would work?

Comment: That could work as long as you don't modify the schema of the content database (unsupported), and you're able to interpret the data that funnels through. Also, you'd want to do this in the most efficient way possible, as SharePoint can be extremely chatty, so treat the notification service as a data firehose. Blog it if you get it working though!